# Applications based on Visual Studio Shell

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I like to know the list of applications using  [Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx) Platform, to understand its capabilities. As of now i know

- [IronPythonStudio](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio)

Answer (score 1):

Embarcadero has Delphi Prism (aka Delphi for .NET) fully implemented in Visual Studio Shell. This is a fully feature Delphi IDE, bigger than IronPython Studio, SQL Server Management Studio and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get all your info [from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/), [or here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/). These two links are the portals into Visual Studio extensibility - be sure to explore the nav menu on the left for the second link.

Answer (score 0):

- [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/default.aspx)
- [AddOn Studio for World of Warcraft](http://www.codeplex.com/AddOnStudio).

Answer (score 0):

[VS.PHP](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/) is built using the Visual Studio core. You can use it as a VS addin, or as a standalone IDE for just PHP. You can develop PHP apps with all the power of VS - great editing, step-through debugging etc. Great tool.